# For which Java class could I replace "Cursor" in order to build some Room Database

Tags: java, android, android-room

I was developing some simple app which make use of a local database using Room library, and I get into the need to replace Cursor class for another one which make the same funcionality.

The main goal is to generate a register ticket, using the data kept in the DB.

Some example of one of this class would be this:

```
public class PenaltyRegister extends RegistroBase {

    /**
     * ATRIBUTOS DE LA CLASE
     */
    private Cursor registerCursor = null;
    private ByteBuffer register;

    private short lengthData = 0;
    private short lengthPenalty = 329;
    private short lengthDataPlus = 23;
    protected int cardDataLength = 150;
    protected int freePenaltyDescriptionLength = 150;
    protected int documentLength = 20;


    private int dailySequenceStock          = 112233;
    private String filenamePenalty          = "PENALTY";


    private char EquitmentType = 3;
    private char EquitmentModel = 3;
    private long serialNumbert = 3456789;
    private char line = 1;
    private int station = 2;
    private char hall = 3;
    private char position = 4;
    private int shiftNumber = 5;
    private long operationNumber = 8;
    private char supportType = 1;
    private char supportSubtype = 1;
    private byte[] cardData = new byte[cardDataLength];
    private char penaltyReason = 167;
    private byte[] freePenaltyDescription = new byte[freePenaltyDescriptionLength];

    private long penaltyAmount = 50;
    private char identification = 1;

    private char identificationType = 1;
    private int countryCode = 724;
    private byte[] document = new byte[documentLength];

    /**
     * METODOS DE LA CLASE
     */

    /**
     * @brief Constructor regitro Penalty //Code 89
     */
    public PenaltyRegister(int code, int version, int dailySeq, String fileName, Cursor p_register, Calendar register_Date, long offsetRegister){
        super(code, version);
        this.registerCursor = p_register;

        Date registerDate = register_Date.getTime();
        this.lengthData = (short) (getLengthRegisterBase() + this.lengthPenalty );
        identification = (char)this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.IDENTIFICATION));
        if(identification == 1)
            this.lengthData += lengthDataPlus;
        setLength(lengthData);
        setDate(registerDate.getTime());
        setFechaRegistro(registerDate);
        setUniversalSequence(this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.UNIVERSAL_SEQ)));
        if(dailySeq == 0)
            dailySeq = dailySequenceStock;
        setDailySequence(dailySeq);
        setOffset(offsetRegister);
        setFileName(fileName);
        for (int st=0;st<cardDataLength; st++)
            cardData[st] = 0x01;
        this.create();
    }

    /**
     * @brief Crea array de bytes del registro
     */
    private final void create() {

        short numOfBytes = this.lengthData;
        register = ByteBuffer.allocate(numOfBytes);
        setProfundidad((char)numOfBytes);

        putUnsignedChar((char) getTipoRegistro());
        putUnsignedChar((char) getVersionRegistro());
        putUnsignedShort(numOfBytes);
        putUnsignedInt(getIndra4b(getFechaRegistro()));
        putUnsignedInt(universalSequence);
        putUnsignedInt(dailySequence);
        putUnsignedInt(offset);
        putArrayBytes(filename);
        putUnsignedChar((char)this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.EQUIPMENT_TYPE)));
        putUnsignedChar((char)this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.EQUIPMENT_MODEL)));
        putUnsignedInt(this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.SERIAL_NUMBER)));
        putUnsignedChar((char)this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.LINE)));
        putUnsignedShort(this.registerCursor.getShort(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.STATION)));
        putUnsignedChar((char)this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.HALL)));
        putUnsignedChar((char)this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.POSITION)));
        putUnsignedShort(this.registerCursor.getShort(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.SHIFT_NUMBER)));
        putUnsignedInt(this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.OPERATION_NUMBER)));
        putUnsignedChar((char)this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.SUPPORT_TYPE)));
        putUnsignedChar((char)this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.SUPPORT_SUBTYPE)));
        //CardData tiene que ser proporcionado por la CTL a través de parámetro del constructor
        putCardDataBytes(Base64.decode(this.registerCursor.getString(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.CARD_DATA)), Base64.DEFAULT));
        int penalty_reason = this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.PENALTY_REASON));
        putUnsignedChar((char)penalty_reason);
        if(penalty_reason == 0){
            setDescription(this.registerCursor.getString(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.PENALTY_DESCRIPTION)));
        }
        putArrayBytes(freePenaltyDescription);
        putUnsignedInt(this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.PENALTY_AMOUNT)));
        putUnsignedChar(identification);

        if (identification == 1) {
            putUnsignedChar((char)this.registerCursor.getInt(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.IDENTIFICATION_TYPE)));
            putUnsignedShort(this.registerCursor.getShort(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.COUNTRY_CODE)));
            setDocument(this.registerCursor.getString(this.registerCursor.getColumnIndex(CoreDbContract.Penalty.DOCUMENT)));
            putArrayBytes(document);
        }

        putUnsignedInt(this.getCRC(this.register.array()));
        this.registerMaster = this.register;
    }

    /**
     * @brief introduce un long en el buffer del registro
     * @param value valor añadido
     */
    private final void putUnsignedInt(long value){
        this.register.put((byte) ((value & 0x000000FF) >> 0));
        this.register.put((byte) ((value & 0x0000FF00) >> 8));
        this.register.put((byte) ((value & 0x00FF0000) >> 16));
        this.register.put((byte) ((value & 0xFF000000) >> 24));
    }

    /**
     * @brief introduce un entero en el buffer del registro
     *
     * @param value valor añadido
     */
    private final void putUnsignedShort(int value){
        this.register.put((byte) ((value & 0x000000FF) >> 0));
        this.register.put((byte) ((value & 0x0000FF00) >> 8));
    }

    /**
     * @brief introduce un byte en el buffer del registro
     * @param value valor añadido
     */
    private final void putUnsignedChar(char value){
        this.register.put((byte)value);
    }

    /**
     * @brief introduce un array de bytes en el buffer del registro
     * @param value valor añadido
     */
    private final void putArrayBytes(byte[] value){
        for(int i=0;i<value.length;i++)
            this.register.put(value[i]);
    }

    /**
     * @brief introduce un array de bytes en el buffer del registro para el campo Card Data
     * (los dos primeros bytes son filtrados)
     * @param value valor añadido
     */
    private final void putCardDataBytes(byte[] value) {
        for(int i=2; i<value.length; i++) {
            this.register.put(value[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief Genera un array de bytes de los valores del registro
     * @return
     */
    public ByteBuffer getBytesRegistro() {
        return register;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Devielve la longitud del registro en Bytes
     * @return Número de bytes que ocopa el registro
     */
    public long getSizeRegistro() {
        return register.array().length;
    }

    /**
      * @brief Calculates and returns the Checksum of the register
      * @param bytes bytes del registro
      * @return Checksum del registro
      */
    private long getChecksum(byte bytes[]) {

        long checksumValue = 0;
        Checksum checksum = new CRC32();

        // update the current checksum with the specified array of bytes
        checksum.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        // get the current checksum value
        checksumValue = checksum.getValue();

        return checksumValue;
    }

    private static int getChecksum16(final byte[] buffer) {
        /* Note the change here */
        int crc = 0x1D0F;
        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length ; j++) {
            crc = ((crc  >>> 8) | (crc  << 8) )& 0xffff;
            crc ^= (buffer[j] & 0xff);//byte to int, trunc sign
            crc ^= ((crc & 0xff) >> 4);
            crc ^= (crc << 12) & 0xffff;
            crc ^= ((crc & 0xFF) << 5) & 0xffff;
        }
        crc &= 0xffff;
        return crc;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Set Penalty description
     * @param p_description nombre archivo del registro
     * @return Registro base
     */
    public RegistroBase setDescription(final String p_description){
        byte[] array = p_description.getBytes();
        for (int i=0; i<p_description.length(); i++)
            this.freePenaltyDescription[i]=array[i];
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Set Document
     * @param p_document nombre archivo del registro
     * @return Registro base
     */
    public RegistroBase setDocument(final String p_document){
        byte[] array = p_document.getBytes();
        for (int i=0; i<p_document.length(); i++)
            this.document[i]=array[i];
        return this;
    }
}
```

I don't know if you can provide some one, but if like this take thanks in advance!

Comment: One of the benefits of Room is not having to worry about Cursor - it is discouraged: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-cursor

Comment: You are right ! So what I should do, it's keep the data from the Cursor, into a new Room database, which I have to build, right?

Comment: It's difficult to say what is best without knowing about your app/product but yes, I would probably do a one-off migration from "old" db to new Room db, this would probably be easier than trying to map the existing data.